# Validating XML using multiple XSD's in Ruby

Tags: xml, ruby, xsd, nokogiri

I'm generating a lot of XMPP stanzas, and want to validate them against the specs available [here](http://xmpp.org/schemas/) in my unit tests.

At the moment I am using Nokogiri to achieve this with something like

```
xml    = Nokogiri::XML( xmpp_stanza)
schema = Nokogiri::XML::Schema( xmpp_schema )

assert schema.valid?( xml )
```

Now this works fine except it gets reported as invalid because each schema only covers one namespace, and my XMPP stanzas have multiple namespaces. For example:

```
Invalid XML: Element '{http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub}pubsub': No matching global element declaration available, but demanded by the strict wildcard.
```

How am I meant to handle multiple schemas to validate a single stanza? Am I meant to first split it apart by namespace and validate each one in isolation?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by [importing](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/el_import.asp) one schema into the other.

e.g.

```
<xs:import namespace="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" schemaLocation="public/xsd/google_base.xsd"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the other namespaces available, you may also be able to alter the schema to include a processContents="lax" directive on relevant "any" nodes in the schema, saying it's okay NOT to validate namespaces you don't have a schema for. I did like so:

```
schema_xml        = Nokogiri::XML(File.read(path))
schema_xml.xpath("//xs:any[@namespace='##other']", 
  {"xs" => "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"}).each do |node|
     node["processContents"] = "lax"
end   
schema = Nokogiri::XML::Schema.from_document( schema_xml )
```

Of course, this means that the external namespaces won't be validated.